# devexpress gridcontrol multiselect

Tags: multi-select, gridcontrol

I know that multiple selection can be done is via the property `SelectionMode = "MultipleRow"` but it is very simple to my need. Do you know any property that enable to extend this functionality to use the keys like Shift and Control for a more rich/intuitive use of multiple selection in the GridControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. just use MultiSelectMode="Cell"

```
<dxg:GridControl  
            x:Name="MyGrid" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"
            ShowBorder="False"
            AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew"
            MaxHeight="10000"
            ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader"
            ShowLoadingPanel="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=true}">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowEditing="False" 

                               MultiSelectMode="Cell"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
</dxd:DocumentPanel
```

>